# React native Creating a module - Invariant Violation: Element

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a simple module, in which I have to print a textView with a message but it tells me:

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string( for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

You likely forgot to export ypur component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of 'App'.

This is the code of the RNFabProgress.java module:

```
package ui.fabprogress;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupManager;

public class RNFabProgress extends ViewGroupManager<ViewGroup> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RNFabProgress";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    protected RelativeLayout createViewInstance(final ThemedReactContext reactContext) {

        /*final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) reactContext.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        viewGroup.setClipChildren(false);
        viewGroup.setClipToPadding(false);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) viewGroup.getChildAt(0);
        frameLayout.setClipChildren(false);
        frameLayout.setClipToPadding(false);*/

        /*LinearLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout frame = new LinearLayout(reactContext);
        frame.setClipChildren(false);
        frame.setClipToPadding(false);

        FrameLayout firstView = new FrameLayout(reactContext);
        firstView.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

        firstView.setClipChildren(false);
        firstView.setClipToPadding(false);

        TextView text1 = new TextView(reactContext);
        text1.setHeight(250);
        text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        text1.setText("Text 1sdasd");

        firstView.addView(text1);

        frame.addView(firstView);*/

        final RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(reactContext);
        TextView textView = new TextView(reactContext);
        textView.setText("hello world");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(960, 150);
        container.addView(textView, lp);

        return container;
    }
}
```

module index.js:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { RNFabProgress } = NativeModules;
export default RNFabProgress;
```

App App.js

```
import RNFabProgress from 'react-native-fab-progress';
....
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNFabProgress />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?